# One AVAudioPlayer to play multiple sounds without re-initialising?

Tags: ios, avfoundation, core-audio, avaudioplayer, avplayer

I'm wanting to use a single instance of an `AVAudioPlayer` to handle a few different quick sound effects, that could be triggered in any order, etc.

As far as I can see, the only way to change the audio file to be played is to re-initialise the player with `initWithContentsOfURL:`.

So, two questions: since that's what I'm doing now, is that alright? More overhead in re-allocating, etc. Should I care? And, is there a way to put all four files in there and tell it to just load them one at a time, but NOT sequentially (i.e. by using the `AVQueuePlayer`)?

Answer (score 1):

If the files are short (which it sounds like), I recommend loading them into an AVAudioBuffer and scheduling these buffers to play on the AVAudioPlayer at the correct time.

See the [WWDC talk](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CB4QFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fdevstreaming.apple.com%2Fvideos%2Fwwdc%2F2014%2F502xxvo7vov799k%2F502%2F502_avaudioengine_in_practice.pdf%3Fdl%3D1&ei=otr0VOuQIcHsmAWHq4CYDQ&usg=AFQjCNFDUXdw3N-7EuNwh2Mz5eEOO-0IWg&bvm=bv.87269000,d.dGY&cad=rja) on AVAudioEngine in Practice ([transcript](http://asciiwwdc.com/2014/sessions/502)).

Comment: Unfortunately that’s iOS8-only, but nice suggestion!

Comment: Can you please be more specific about what OS version you're targeting?

Comment: Yes, on iOS7 AVAudioPlayer is tightly coupled with the file or data buffer that it is initialized with. So I don't see you getting around a re-initialization. Another general idea would be to concatenate your small files into one larger one and seek and play at the correct offset, but the API doesn't support seek/offset playback. Have you looked at AVPlayer (instead of AVAudioPlayer)? Presumably, you're not playing an iPod library url?